# What seems to be the general consensus on retrying failed tests automatically?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

From time to time, I find myself spending quite a bit of time diagnosing and troubleshooting false positives that come from my automated tests.  Out of a few hundred tests driven in a browser, around 4% of them fail with seemingly no rhyme or reason, and they tend to be different each and every time.  For example, some simple shared steps may work in one example but then fail for no reason in another.

I've continued to spend time troubleshooting and improving these areas (improving waiting on elements, improved preconditions, etc) but it seems to only help marginally.  Anecdotally, this phenomenon seems to worsen when using IE11 vs Chrome.

I've come across a neat gem called `rspec-retry` which simply retries any failed tests as they come along.  I'm wondering what the consensus is with this approach, as I'm adamant of making sure that I'm "testing the right way".

Comment: My experience is much the same, I've done like you and slowly improved my tests.  I've also slowly improved my scripts so that failures are rerun before I do any diagnosis

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Not sure why the downvote came about!  I thought it was a good question to open up discussion about UI and QA testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: there is no consensus, apart from "mostly people don't do this".

Mostly - we figure out what it is that's causing the specs to fail and fix them. These are called "intermittent spec failures" and they are a regular pain (especially capybara ones). But they are worth fixing because they will keep coming back.

Refactor, refactor, refactor: there is a way to fix all of them - even if you have to resort to the ugly `sleep(1)` (* shudder *).